# The attachable property "ThemeDictionaries" was not found in type "ResourceDictionary"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary, app.xaml

The following code is within app.xaml on a Windows Phone 8 application. It receives the error `The attachable property "ThemeDictionaries" was not found in type "ResourceDictionary"`. Likewise, it does not set the background. I'm trying to set the background across the entire application with the option to change it using `(App.Current.Resources["BackgroundImage"] as ImageBrush).ImageSource = imgSrc;`  through c# code.

```c#
<Application
    x:Class="MyApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">  
     <Application.Resources>
          <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
              <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundImage" ImageSource="Assets/BackgroundDefault.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
              </ResourceDictionary>
              <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundImage" ImageSource="Assets/BackgroundDark.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
              </ResourceDictionary>
           </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallPanoramaTitle">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
                </ContentPresenter>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </Application.Resources>
      <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
       </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` not available in windows phone silverlight applications.

You can use the [ThemeManager](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager) library to mange your themes in WP silverlight. This is an excellent library and its available in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager/) also.

See [this](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/03/theme-manager-library-for-wp.html) page to understand how to use ThemeManager . You can also load custom theme files

Comment: Thanks, ThemeManager seems broken though. Simply using `ThemeManager.SetBackground(new Uri("Assets/backgroundImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));` does nothing and has no effect when called on a new panorama page.

Comment: Make sure you are not setting background color in each page